# Tkinter Canvas messing up the grid

Tags: python, tkinter, chess

I am trying to make a Chess game, and I am making the graphics using the tkinter library in Python. I made a subclass of Canvas called `chessPiece`. Using the following code, I distributed it onto the tkinter grid:

```py
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                if (i%2==0 and j%2==0) or (i%2==1 and j%2==1):
                    color='blanched almond'
                else:
                    color='olive drab'
                self.cells.append(chessPiece(self,color,(i,j)))
                self.cells[i*8+j].grid(row=i,column=j)
```

and it works perfectly. The real problem comes later, when I try to add 5 buttons, 4 to a new 8th row, and 1 to a new 9th row, using the following code:

```py
        self.master.qButton = Button(text='Queen',command=self.createQueen)
        self.master.rButton = Button(text='Rook',command=self.createRook)
        self.master.bButton = Button(text='Bishop',command=self.createBishop)
        self.master.kButton = Button(text='Knight',command=self.createKnight)
        self.master.conButton = Button(text='CONFIRM PIECE',command=self.conPiece)
        self.master.qButton.grid(row=8,column=0,columnspan=2)
        self.master.rButton.grid(row=8,column=2,columnspan=2)
        self.master.bButton.grid(row=8,column=4,columnspan=2)
        self.master.kButton.grid(row=8,column=6,columnspan=2)
        self.master.conButton.grid(row=9,column=2,columnspan=4)
```

Instead of fitting nicely underneath the board, the first button is centered under the board and takes up the entire space, and the rest of the four buttons are off to the side of the board, making some 9th column, while I am only trying to make a second column!

I am posting the entire code here. Note that I have only put in partial logic for pawns, and that I have made it so that all the black pawns are white for now. The code I am having problems with is the `promote(self)` function in the `chessPiece` class, which is when a pawn is being promoted, so just take a piece with a white pawn to promote it quickly and see the outcome of my code.

Full Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def cL(coord):
    return coord[0]*8+coord[1]

class chessPiece(Canvas):
    pics = {\
            'bpawn':'bPawn.png',\
            'bbish':'bBishop.png',\
            'bking':'bKing.png',\
            'brook':'bRook.png',\
            'bknit':'bKnight.png',\
            'bquen':'bQueen.png',\
            'wpawn':'wPawn.png',\
            'wbish':'wBishop.png',\
            'wking':'wKing.png',\
            'wrook':'wRook.png',\
            'wknit':'wKnight.png',\
            'wquen':'wQueen.png',\
            }
    def __init__(self,master,BG,coord):
        self.bgColor = BG
        self.coord=coord
        self.cLoc=coord[0]*8+coord[1]
        self.width=50
        self.height=50
        Canvas.__init__(self,master,width=self.width,height=self.height,bg=BG,\
                        highlightthickness=0,relief=RAISED)
        self.piece = 'none'
        self.bind("<Button-1>",self.move)

    def createPiece(self,pieceName, size=(50,50)):
        self.createImage(pieceName,size)
        self.piece = pieceName

    def createImage(self,pieceName,size):
        filename = self.pics[pieceName]
        self.im = Image.open(filename)
        self.resizePic(size)
        self.img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.pic = self.create_image(self.width/2,self.height/2,anchor=CENTER,\
                                     image=self.img)

    def resizePic(self,size):
        self.im = self.im.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)

    def removePiece(self):
        self.piece = 'none'
        self.delete(self.pic)

    def move(self, misc = ''):
        if self['bg']=='lightgreen':
            self.unhighlight()
            self.master.lastCell=-1
            return 0
        if not self.master.hasHighlighted:
            self.master.cells[self.master.lastCell].unhighlight()
            self.highlight()
            self.master.lastCell=self.cLoc
        else:
            if self.master.lastCell==-1:
                return 0
            if self.master.validMove(self.master.cells[self.master.lastCell], self):
                self.master.cells[self.master.lastCell].unhighlight()
                self.highlight()
                self.createPiece(self.master.cells[self.master.lastCell].piece)
                self.master.cells[self.master.lastCell].removePiece()
                if (self.piece=='bpawn' and self.coord[0]==7) or (self.piece=='wpawn' and self.coord[0]==0):
                    self.promote()
                self.master.lastCell=self.cLoc
                self.master.toggleTurn()
            

    def highlight(self):
        self['bg']='lightgreen'
        self.master.hasHighlighted = True

    def unhighlight(self):
        self['bg']=self.bgColor
        self.master.hasHighlighted = False

    def promote(self):
        self.master.qButton = Button(text='Queen',command=self.createQueen)
        self.master.rButton = Button(text='Rook',command=self.createRook)
        self.master.bButton = Button(text='Bishop',command=self.createBishop)
        self.master.kButton = Button(text='Knight',command=self.createKnight)
        self.master.conButton = Button(text='CONFIRM PIECE',command=self.conPiece)
        self.master.qButton.grid(row=8,column=0,columnspan=2)
        self.master.rButton.grid(row=8,column=2,columnspan=2)
        self.master.bButton.grid(row=8,column=4,columnspan=2)
        self.master.kButton.grid(row=8,column=6,columnspan=2)
        self.master.conButton.grid(row=9,column=2,columnspan=4)

    def createQueen(self):
        if self.piece[0]=='w':
            self.createPiece('wquen')
        else:
            self.createPiece('bquen')

    def createRook(self):
        if self.piece[0]=='w':
            self.createPiece('wrook')
        else:
            self.createPiece('brook')

    def createBishop(self):
        if self.piece[0]=='w':
            self.createPiece('wbish')
        else:
            self.createPiece('bbish')

    def createKnight(self):
        if self.piece[0]=='w':
            self.createPiece('wknit')
        else:
            self.createPiece('bknit')

    def conPiece(self):
        if self.piece == 'bpawn' or self.piece=='wpawn':
            return 0
        self.master.qButton.grid_remove()
        self.master.rButton.grid_remove()
        self.master.bButton.grid_remove()
        self.master.kButton.grid_remove()
        self.master.conButton.grid_remove()

class chessBoard(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.cells=[]
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                if (i%2==0 and j%2==0) or (i%2==1 and j%2==1):
                    color='blanched almond'
                else:
                    color='olive drab'
                self.cells.append(chessPiece(self,color,(i,j)))
                self.cells[i*8+j].grid(row=i,column=j)
        self.rowconfigure(8,minsize=8)
        self.cells[0].createPiece('brook')
        self.cells[1].createPiece('bknit')
        self.cells[2].createPiece('bbish')
        self.cells[3].createPiece('bquen')
        self.cells[4].createPiece('bking')
        self.cells[5].createPiece('bbish')
        self.cells[6].createPiece('bknit')
        self.cells[7].createPiece('brook')
        for i in range(8):
            self.cells[cL((1,i))].createPiece('wpawn')
            self.cells[cL((6,i))].createPiece('wpawn')
        self.cells[cL((7,0))].createPiece('wrook')
        self.cells[cL((7,1))].createPiece('wknit')
        self.cells[cL((7,2))].createPiece('wbish')
        self.cells[cL((7,3))].createPiece('wquen')
        self.cells[cL((7,4))].createPiece('wking')
        self.cells[cL((7,5))].createPiece('wbish')
        self.cells[cL((7,6))].createPiece('wknit')
        self.cells[cL((7,7))].createPiece('wrook')
        self.lastCell = -1
        self.turn = 0
        self.hasHighlighted = False
        

    def toggleTurn(self):
        self.turn = (self.turn+1)%2

    def validMove(self, oCell, nCell):
        if oCell.piece=='wpawn':
            return self.validMoveWP(oCell, nCell)
        elif oCell.piece=='bpawn':
            return self.validMoveBP(oCell, nCell)
        else:
            return False

    def validMoveWP(self, oCell, nCell):
        if self.turn != 0:
            return False
        if oCell.coord[1]==nCell.coord[1]:
            if oCell.coord[0]==6:
                if self.cells[cL((5,oCell.coord[1]))].piece != 'none':
                    return False
                if (nCell.coord[0]==5 or nCell.coord[0]==4):
                    return True
            elif (nCell.coord[1]==oCell.coord[1]):
                    return True
        elif abs(oCell.coord[1]-nCell.coord[1])==1 and \
             oCell.coord[0]-nCell.coord[0]==1 and \
             nCell.piece != 'none':
            return True
        return False

    def validMoveBP(self, oCell, nCell):
        if self.turn != 1:
            return False
        if oCell.coord[1]==nCell.coord[1]:
            if oCell.coord[0]==1:
                if self.cells[cL((2,oCell.coord[1]))].piece != 'none':
                    return False
                if (nCell.coord[0]==2 or nCell.coord[0]==3):
                    return True
            elif (nCell.coord[1]==oCell.coord[1]):
                    return True
        elif abs(oCell.coord[1]-nCell.coord[1])==1 and \
             oCell.coord[0]-nCell.coord[0]==-1 and \
             nCell.piece != 'none':
            return True
        return False
        
        
def play_chess():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Chess')
    game = chessBoard(root)
    root.mainloop()
play_chess()
```

[image: bBishop]

[image: bKnight]

[image: bPawn]

[image: bQueen]

[image: bRook]

You will need to save the pictures named as the picture-descriptions I have given them. For example, you will need to save the black pawn picture as bPawn.png.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did not set the `master` of those buttons, so it will be assigned to the `root` window.  Set the `master` to `self.master`: `Button(self.master, text=....)`.

Comment: Please reduce the code down to a [mcve]. For example, if the problem is related to adding buttons to the layout, we don't need any of the code to do the movement of the pieces. We probably also don't need all of the pieces. For the purposes of this question you can probably just use the same piece over and over.

Comment: I didn't know exactly which part of the code was causing the problem, so I added all of it. Anyway, @acw1668: thanks so much! I have been making this mistake over and over again and now I know how to fix it :)